# How or to whom should I report a suspicion of a bug in the scala.collection.mutable._ classes?

Tags: scala

What channels should I go through to report a bug in Scala?

As per another question I have what looks like a bug in the mutable collection `ListBuffer` and `LinkedLis`t. Below all in one file:

```
object MyObject {

   def myFunc() = {
       var mutable = scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[Moo]
       mutable += new Moo()   // <--- GIVES ERROR AS DESCRIBED BELOW
   }
}

class Moo() {
  val hi:String = "Hello"
}
```

The error: `Type mismatch, expected String, actual Moo`

Am I being dim, or is this actually a bug?

thanks.

Comment: If you fix your code, it works fine.

Comment: thanks. I guess my confusion was that on the other question I posted the chap helping swore blind the code (as is) should work. My apologies for being a donkey

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace your declaration of mutable with:

```
var mutable = scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[Moo]()
```

If you try to enter your original line (e.g. in console), you'll see the following:

```
scala> var mutable = scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[Moo]
<console>:8: error: missing arguments for method apply in class GenericCompanion;
follow this method with `_' if you want to treat it as a partially applied function
   var mutable = scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[Moo]
```

That means that your original declaration (without parens) wasn't the valid way to instantiate the container: under the hood, it will be interpreted as an incomplete function call. (Which is a bit confusing, taking into account that in Scala one can omit parens in many other cases).

Answer (score 1):

This is why people don't like `+` to mean "string concatenation" as an add-on.

Since nobody asked about the original error message, I'll guess that you really had:

```
var mutable = scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer
mutable += new Moo()
```

which does produce that error.

```
scala> object X
defined object X

scala> var x = X
x: X.type = X$@2bad298f

scala> x += 1
<console>:10: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int(1)
 required: String
              x += 1
                   ^
```

Or, it's just possible you didn't try to compile the code you posted?

To answer your question, SO is a good place to ask these sorts of questions.